# Google App Script is not running at all not even the debugger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a pretty simple script on Google Spreadsheet, it is need to read the fields and send emails when in one particular column it reads "yes" and after that it marks another cell to "Sent" - to avoid repeating sending it.
 when trying to test it it seems that it is not running not even the debugger.

I have never got this before, can someone help?

```js
function sendMail(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var hwToCheckValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(hwToCheckValues[2][5]);
  
  
  
  for (i = 0; i < hwToCheckValues.length; i++){
    if (hwToCheckValues[i][5] == 'Yes' || hwToCheckValues[i][5] == 'yes'){
      if  (hwToCheckValues[i][7] != 'Sent'){
    
      var firstName = hwToCheckValues[i][1];
      var lastName = hwToCheckValues[i][2];
      var emailAddress = hwToCheckValues[i][3];
      var comments = hwToCheckValues[i][7];
      var fileLink = hwToCheckValues[i][9];
      
      var html = [];
      var summary = '';
  
  if (comments != '') {
    summary = 'Your Home Work got checked ' +
        'Comments: ' + comments +
          ' You Can find the file with the full comments here: ' + fileLink;
  } else {
    summary = 'Your Home Work got checked ' +
          ' You Can find the file with the full comments here: ' + fileLink;
  }
  html.push('<html>',
              '<head></head>',
                 '<body>',
                  '<table style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica; ' +
                       'border-collapse:collapse;font-size:10pt; ' +
                       'color:#444444; border: solid 1px #dddddd;" ' +
                       'width="600" cellpadding=20>',
                     '<tr>',
                       '<td>',
                         '<p>Hello,</p>',
                         '<p>' + summary + '</p>',
                         '<p>Cheers<br />Sepreia College Team</p>',
                       '</td>',
                     '</tr>',
                   '</table>',
                 '</body>',
             '</html>'
           );

  if (emailAddress != '') {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: 'Your HW got Feedback',
      htmlBody: html.join('\n')
    });
    hwToCheckValues[i][8] == 'Sent';
  }
          }  
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you (try to) run this script? Can you run any scripts?

Comment: Before running the debugger, click the line numbe rin the editor next the first for line: `  for (i = 0; i < hwToCheckValues.length; i++){` to place a red dot on the line number.  Then run the debugger by clicking the bug icon. The process will stop at the line you selected and show the variables as they are defined at that point. Click the + next to the hwToCheckValues object to expand it. Make sure you have values which will return true for your IF statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working now.

Comment: I had this same issue today. I'm running in debug mode and it keeps hanging. I kept setting my breakpoints sooner and sooner to see what it was hanging on, and I got to setting my first breakpoint as my first line of active code in my script! It is just hanging there...  not executing *anything at all*! What could cause this to happen? I don't have any error message to go off of or anything. It just sits and spins.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: I let it keep running, and it's even past the 6 minute maximum execution time limit... it didn't even stop on that. Still sitting and spinning. I stopped it manually, had '2:00:02 PM Notice Execution started` and `2:07:39 PM Execution cancelled`. Over 7 minutes...

Comment: So, I had accidentally typed some nonsense stuff at the top of my file (probably when I thought a different window was active). I figured it out by actually trying to Run (not in debug mode) another script in the same file. Then I get an error I can see. Very odd that it stops in Run mode but keeps trying to run in Debug Mode.